# Do any scriptures apart from the Brahmavaivarta Purana forbid sannyasa?

Tags: identification-request, kali-yuga, sannyasa, brahma-vaivarta-purana

The Brahmavaivarta Purana, Krishna-Janma-Khanda 185.180 states:

> asvamedham gavalambham sannyasam palapaitrkam
>   devarena sutopattim kalau panca vivarjayet
>
> Five things are forbidden in the age of Kali – horse-sacrifice, cow-sacrifice, **acceptance of sannyasa**, offering flesh to the forefathers and begetting a child in the womb of the wife of one’s elder brother.

As you can see the above verse forbids accepting sannyasa in Kali-Yuga. I want to know whether any other scripture apart from the Brahmavaivarta Purana forbids sannyasa?

Comment: Two things.  First of all. this verse is considered by many to be an interpolation.  Second of all, Gaudiya Vaishnavas, who are the main people who cite this verse, believe that it only forbids Ekadandi Sanyasa, not Tridandi Sanyasa.